# Directions parts are not generated in Java (Generated) although build.gradle sync successfully

Tags: android, gradle, android-safe-args

Directions parts are not generated in Java (Generated) even though I have specified fragment actions in Android Studio and many time rebuild project[enter image description here][1]. So I can't use directions. What would be the reason?

Builde.graddle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        def nav_version = "2.5.2"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false


}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

build.graddle[app]

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs")
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.4.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.3.0'


}
```

[Not generated(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIOan.png)

Comment: Try to rebuild?

Comment: Rebuild many times but still not working.

Comment: what is your gradle version [gradle-wrapper.properties],
can you also add the following line in plugins
`id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin' version '2.5.3' apply false`